# Different constraints for each UILabel line

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, constraints

Is it possible to use different constraints for each UILabel line? In my case i'm using a image an than a label, but sometimes when the label has more than one single line, instead of breaking line and starting right from where it started the first line, i need to start under the image which is on UIImage left side. Would it be possible?

(Like NSTEXTATTACHMENT BUT ENVOLVING CONSTRAINTS)

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean, maybe you can include a screenshot / image - if you cannot upload one directly, just upload it somewhere else and post the link.

Comment: @luk2302 it's a NSTextAttachment with image, because i need to flush the left space that was first used by the image in the first line. Got it? Thank you anyway

Comment: @luk2302 what i was first purposing was sort of different constraint for each line, but it's not possible since a label is a single view, not every line is a new view so i'll have to do it as a NSTextAttachment

Answer (score 0):

you could use a `UITextView` instead and set its `exclusionPaths` property. looks like this:

```
CGRect textViewFrame = [self.textView convertRect:self.imageView.bounds 
                                         fromView:self.imageView];

UIBezierPath *imageViewPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:textViewFrame];
self.textView.textContainer.exclusionPaths = @[imageViewPath];
```